# jQuery offset().top returns 0 when using less

Tags: jquery, less, offset

I am having a problem for a while now. I hope someone could help me.

I'm working on a WordPress project and I need an element's top offset. I'm using jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var distance = jQuery('div').offset().top;
});
```

But it returns 0.

Only when I'm using window.load() and a timeout it returns the right value:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery(window).load(function($) {
        setTimeout(function () { 
            var distance = jQuery('div').offset().top;  
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Can somebody give me advise how to fix this. Because using on load and a timeout is just a quick fix. Not the right way... I've searched for other threads but can't find a solution.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I found out that I'm only having this problem when I'm using LESS. When I turn develop mode off and compile my LESS to CSS offset works fine.

Comment: `div` is a very broad selector is there only one div in your html?  But your  problem is most likely not all your images have loaded by the time the document ready fires but without a [mcve] we cannot really do anything but guess

Comment: In this example I used just a general "div". In the project it selfs I call the class name, which is unique.

Comment: Browsers always work with compiled css. So no matter which preprocessor are you using: sass or less.

Comment: It seems that the `div` is not loaded yet. Is it dynamic generated or it comes from the initial code?

Comment: Initial code. Also images are not the problem, since this problem also occurs when there are no images at all.

It only occurs when I load my stylesheet using a less-file, very strange.